# Elevation for Floating action button is not working

Tags: android, material-components, material-components-android

I'm using the material components FloatingActionButton https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/

In that, I can't able to add elevation for my fab I tried using the below code but it's not working
`app:elevation="12dp"`
`app:borderWidth="0dp"`

Here is my xml.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/mfab"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mainlay"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-28dp"
        app:elevation="12dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_directions_walk_white_18dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK fab overrides elevation value. So there are two possible solutions:
1. You get source code of fab and change value of elevation
2. You create your own implementation.
I'd suggest you to use first solution.

Comment: Where do I change the values of elevation of fab, I tried changing it through xml but didn't worked out.

Comment: @Adarsh you can't change elevation of fab

Comment: @Arthur Can you share the detailed answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining a custom style inherited from Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton with your desired elevation, and set the custom style on your FAB instance?

Comment: @wcschi Can you share the detailed answer ?